# Solution in general for a seemingly simple problem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be a closed, bounded, convex set in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $\mathbb{x}=[x_1,\dots,x_N]$ be any arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{S}$. Then what can we comment on the problem 
\begin{align}
\min_{t\in \mathbb{R},\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{S}}&~~t\\\
\mbox{s.t.}~~&x_i\leq t,~~i=1,\dots,N
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for exactly. Here is another way of looking at the problem (basically the dual).

$\Sigma = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N | x_i \ge 0, \sum_i x_i = 1 \}$, and 
$\sigma_S$ is the support function of $S$.

The interchange of the $\max$, $\min$ is justified by a version of von Neumann's minimax theorem.

\begin{eqnarray}
\min_{t, x\in S} \{ t | x_i \le t\} &=& \min_{x \in S} \max_i x_i \\
&=& \min_{x \in S} \max_{\mu \in \Sigma} \langle \mu, x \rangle \\
&=& \max_{\mu \in \Sigma} \min_{x \in S}  \langle \mu, x \rangle \\
&=& \max_{\mu \in \Sigma} ( -\max_{x \in S}  \langle -\mu, x \rangle ) \\
&=& -\min_{\mu \in \Sigma} \max_{x \in S}  \langle -\mu, x \rangle  \\
&=& -\min_{\mu \in \Sigma} \sigma_S(-\mu)  \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Brilliant!! This is sort of what I needed. I would like to ask if this interchange is possible because of the convexity of $\mathbb{S}$ and $\mathbb{\Sigma}$

Comment: In this case linearity of $\mu \mapsto \langle \mu, x \rangle$ and $x \mapsto \langle \mu, x \rangle$ along with convexity and compactness of $\Sigma, S$. There are much more general statements, but this is sufficient here. At some level, this sort of $\min$, $\max$ interchange is at the heart of duality.

Comment: Could you please point me to some references on this. Google Search returned with results from game theory.

Comment: I only have Rockafellar with me at the moment, it has a suitable result: Corollary 37.3.2 states: Let $C$ and $D$ be non-empty closed convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively, and let $K$ be a continuous finite concave-convex function on $C \times D$. If either $C$ or $D$ is bounded, one has $\inf_{v \in D} \sup_{u \in C} K(u,v) = \sup_{u \in C} \inf_{v \in D}  K(u,v)$.

Comment: I guess that is good enough for my application. Let us say $\mathbb{S}$  is not convex, does it become a inequality?

Comment: oh, I am sorry!!. When I look at it again, I don't exactly understand the second equality $\min_{x \in S} \max_i x_i = \min_{x \in S} \max_{\mu \in \Sigma}$ ?

Comment: Show  that $\max_i x_i = \max_{\mu \in \Sigma} \sum_k \mu_k x_k$. The definition of $\Sigma$ is crucial here.

Comment: ya, I get it :):). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem reminded me of some type of epigraph form. For example, for the following problem (P1)

$\qquad\,\,\,\,\,\min_x f_0(x)\\
\text{subject to } f_i(x)\le0,\,i=1,\ldots,n\\
\qquad \qquad \,\,\,h_i(x)=0,\,i=1,\ldots,m$

The epigraph form is

$\qquad\,\,\,\,\,\min_{x,t} t\\
\text{subject to } f_0(x)\le t\\
\qquad \qquad \,\,\,f_i(x)\le0,\,i=1,\ldots,n\\
\qquad \qquad \,\,\,h_i(x)=0,\,i=1,\ldots,m$

Which is equivalent to (P1); $(x,t)$ is optimal for the epigraph form if and only if $x$ is optimal for (P1) and $t=f_0(x)$. A geometrical interpretation can be seen below (from Boyd)

[image]

However, in your problem it seems as though we wish to find the smallest scalar $t$ which defines some *orthant* (not epigraph), such that all $x_i$ live in this orthant and the set $\mathbb{S}$. In hindsight, the epigraph form may not be of much use here, but hopefully provides some intuition.

Comment: it does help in one and two dimensions. I would like to see how this generalizes on to $N$ dimensions. Thanks for your help